# Unable to override font-family in lightning-input label using LWC styling hooks

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

How to override the font-family using styling hooks? I tried writing a custom CSS class with --lwc-fontFamily property set to my custom value and applied that CSS class to the lightning input element. However, it defaults to Lato. I checked the CSS in the browser and it seems there is a body{font-family:var(--lwc-fontFamily, Lato) written there. How to achieve this?

I tried something like this

```
.custom-css{
--lwc-fontFamily:Roboto-Regular;
--lwc-formLabelFontSize:1rem;
--lwc-colorTextLabel:#000000;
}
```

Comment: What code did you write, specifically?

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/359291/edit) your question to add the code you have tried so far - even if it does not work - and *exactly* (e.g., exact error text, details on unexpected behavior) how it is not working. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include **...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). ...** ")*

Comment: @sfdcfox What an honor to get a comment from the legendary sfdcfox :) Well I had made a silly mistake thinking everything needs a styling hook. I wrote something like this .custom-css{---lwc-fontFamily:Roboto-Regular; --lwc-formLabelFontSize:1rem;--lwc-colorTextLabel: #000000;}  Turns out I didnt need to use --lwc-fontFamily. Just font-family would have done the job. But it is weird though. Kept inheriting from body{font-family:var(---lwc-fontFamily, Lato)}

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! Please do remember to [edit] your code into the question if you still need help, or you can self-answer if you figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had made a silly mistake thinking everything needs a styling hook. I wrote something like this

```
.custom-css{
--lwc-fontFamily:Roboto-Regular; 
--lwc-formLabelFontSize:1rem;
--lwc-colorTextLabel: #000000;
}
```

Turns out I didnt need to use --lwc-fontFamily. Just font-family would have done the job. But it is weird though. Kept inheriting from

```
body{
font-family:var(--lwc-fontFamily, Lato);
}
```

Anyways, the problem was solved using font-family instead of --lwc-fontFamily